# radial gradient shape in swiftui

Tags: swiftui

[image]

hey everyone, I designed some stuff in figma and now that Im trying to transfer everything to swiftui I'm having some troubles. Does anyone know how I can make this ellipse shaped gradient in swiftui? I tried the swuiftui inspector but it just gave me a circular shape. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RadialGradient` by applying `scaleEffect` modifier to shrink it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let gradient = Gradient(
        stops: [
            .init(color: .green.opacity(0.4), location: 0),
            .init(color: .green.opacity(0.5), location: 0.7),
            .init(color: .green.opacity(0), location: 1),
        ]
    )
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Rectangle()
                .fill(
                    RadialGradient(
                        gradient: gradient,
                        center: .center,
                        startRadius: 0,
                        endRadius: geometry.size.width / 2
                    )
                )
                .scaleEffect(x: 1, y: geometry.size.height / geometry.size.width, anchor: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

Since iOS 15 you can get rid of both `GeometryReader` and `scaleEffect` using `EllipticalGradient`, so it may be more performant, or at least less code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let gradient = Gradient(
        stops: [
            .init(color: .green.opacity(0.4), location: 0),
            .init(color: .green.opacity(0.5), location: 0.7),
            .init(color: .green.opacity(0), location: 1),
        ]
    )
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(
                EllipticalGradient(
                    gradient: gradient,
                    center: .center
                )
            )
    }
}
```

Both variants looks totally the same:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

iOS15 only :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(
                .ellipticalGradient(
                    colors: [.red, .orange, .yellow],
                    center: .center,
                    startRadiusFraction: 0.2,
                    endRadiusFraction: 0.6
                )
            )
    }
}
```

or :

```
struct ContentView2: View {
    let gradient = Gradient(stops:
                                [.init(color: .red, location: 0.2),
                                 .init(color: .orange, location: 0.6),
                                 .init(color: .yellow, location: 0.8)])
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(
                .elliptical(gradient,
                            center: .center,
                            startRadiusFraction: 0.1,
                            endRadiusFraction: 0.6)
            )
    }
}
```

[image: example]